# Is there a way to add references to C++ class members to a vector without explicitly adding them?

Tags: c++, class, composition

I'm trying to determine what pattern(s) may be used to declare a C++ class in a more "compositional" and less "imperative" way.

I'm trying to write a class that includes multiple `MyDescriptor` members. The `MyDescriptor` needs to be initialized by the `MyHost` classes constructor and it iterates over references to the `MyHost` members to do this.

Is there a way to declare `MyHost` implementations that don't require adding class members references to a container separately?

```
class MyDescriptor {
public:
  string name;
  string fqn;
  MyHost(string n) : name(n) {}
  void init(string host) {
    fqn = host + ":" + name;
  }
  void do_thing() {
    // subclasses to special things.
  }

}

class MyHost {
public:
  vector<MyDescriptor*> descriptors;
  string name
  MyHost(string n, vector<MyDescriptor*> d) : name(n),descriptors(d) {
    for (MyDescriptor *d : descriptors) {
      d->init(name);
    }
  }
}

MyHostImpl : public MyHost {
public:
  // descriptors must be accessible as members like this
  MyDescriptor d_1 = MyDescriptor("abc");
  MyDescriptor d_2 = MyDescriptor("123");

  MyHostImpl(string n) : MyHost(n, {&d_1, &d_2}) {} // This is the issue

  void do_thing_1() {
    // UPDATE: This is loose example - but what is important to
    // know is that developers need to access / use descriptors
    // in methods like this.
    d_1.do_thing();
  }

}
```

I'd ideally like a way to stop declaring the `descriptors` items explicitly; this `{&d_1, &d_2}` is what I'd like to eliminate. My team uses a similar pattern and are constantly frustrated by accidentally not adding to descriptors to the vector after adding it to the class.

Comment: To make sure I understand: you need to retain the `descriptors` *member* (or an equivalent) for some purpose, yes?  So the question is about how to get it initialized, or how to implement a replacement that does not require explicit initialization?

Comment: It might help to show a representative example of how `descriptors` is used.

Comment: Look up `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes you are correct. `descriptors` need to be class members. They are currently initialized in a lazy way and are use a lot on the class internally/externally. The `hosts` are essentially just wrapper classes that have specific abstractions around groups of `descriptors`. 

An alternative implementation where descriptors are still declared as members and are initialized in some way would be an ideal solution. Preferable `MyHost` implementations wouldn't have to do explicit initialization. 

I'll update the sample ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invert the ctor semantics. Instead of host ctor accepting descriptor pointers, Have descriptor's ctor take a host reference and add itself to to the host vector:

```
    MyDescriptor::MyDescriptor(MyDescriptor const&)=delete;
    auto& MyDescriptor::operator=(MyDescriptor const&)=delete;
    MyDescriptor::MyDescriptor(string n, MyHost& h): name{n},fqn{n+":"+h.get_name()}
    {
        h.add(this);
    };

    MyHost::MyHost(string n):name{n}{};
    void MyHost::add(MyDescriptor* d){
        descriptors.push_back(d);
    };
    auto& MyHost::get_name()const{
        return name;
    };
```

This way you can not forget to add descriptors to the host or the compiler cries.

```
MyHostImpl::MyHostImpl(string n):
    MyHost{n},
    d_1{"abc",*this},/*compiler kills you if you forget this line*/
    d_2{"123",*this}/*compiler kills you if you forget this line*/
{};
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy that what is needed is `a class that includes multiple MyDescriptor members` . To be clear `descriptors` have to be members.

Comment: @AageTorleif I did not include the 'MyHostImpl' in the post. Just try to define that class, and you'll find it fits. It does not magically create initializers for descriptor members, it rather saves you from forgetting to initialize theme. On 2nd thought, I'm gonna add the ctor for ' MyHostImpl' to the post.

Comment: Oh! that's actually pretty nice. I'm not a fan of the `descriptor` type requiring the `host` type but with a little type-refactoring I think this can work.

Comment: @AageTorleif I do not like this code either, but it was a fast patch for some legacy code. I mimiced it after QT widget library. But keep your mind open.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a a way to do directly what you're asking for, in C++14 at least, but it involves a bunch of dark voodoo. In this Meeting C++ 2018 talk:

[Better C++14 reflections - Antony Polukhin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlNUNxLtBI0)

Antony explains how is able to iterate over all members of a struct with access to their types. He uses it to print values on some output stream, but you could use the same method to push back addresses into a `std::vector<MyDescriptor*>`.

Having said that - I think you should just avoid this pattern. Just create a vector of MyDescriptors to begin with, and work with a reference to that. Why use a vector of pointers that requires so much contortion to produce?

Comment: "Why use a vector of pointers that requires so much contortion to produce?" I think it was meant to make some legacy code more simple. It may have done that - but it's hard to track-down issues when we don't follow the boilerplate (initializing the vector). 

Sometimes we have a few dozen `descriptors` on a `host` and it would just be easier to not have to explicitly define the vector.

Comment: "I think it was meant to make some legacy code more simple." <- The guy who will follow you in your current job will probably say the same thing, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how you'd imagine that would work. C++ has no reflection, so there's no way for you to iterate over it's class members and check their type. So, sorry, not possible for all I know. You could of course use some workarounds, such as simply using the underlying base vector directly instead of declaring the two descriptors as member variables (is there any reason you need that?) and then implicitly pass them in the Base constructor, but what you're aiming for is not possible.

Edit: Apparently it's possible with some dark voodoo magic, refer to the comment below.

Comment: Actually, C++ has quite a bit of reflection if you play your cards right, and you can _definitely_ iterate over a plain struct's data members and check their type. See my answer. Of course - if it's a class with private/protected members, non-default constructors etc then you can't.

Comment: It's not that I want to iterate over the members per se - a better way of getting the object assigned to the class-member and a reference to it in the vector is all that's really necessary. And by better way I mean one that's simple to declare and hard to make mistakes with.